# jQuery children selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="form-fields">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="info">Info</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the children selector how can I select span.info? I have tried doing:

`$('.form-fields').children('.row .info')`

But this didn't work for me.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers everyone. If I assign the container DIV as follows:

`var parentDiv = $('.form-fields')`

Then using the var 'parentDiv' what is the best way to select span.info?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to get non-direct descendants:

```
$('.form-fields').find('.row .info')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use `.children`?

```
$('.form-fields span.info')
```

Comment: @gstar: you're better off with the `find` then.

Answer (score 2):

`.children()` will only grab `immediate` child nodes. You need to invoke `.find()`.

```
$('.form-fields').find('.row .info')
```

or even

```
$('.form-fields').find('.row').find('.info');
```

just by selector

```
$('.form-fields .info')
```

Reference: [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-fields').children('.row').children('.info')
```

you can test it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert( $('.form-fields').children('.row').children('.info').length);


});
```